# Duplicating file pointers?

Tags: c, file-io

Just a quick question: Is there a way to duplicate a file pointer (those returned by `fopen()`), similar to how `dup()` duplicates a file handlers returned by functions like `open()`?

Basically, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("some_file", "r");
FILE *fp2 = /* do something to duplicate the file pointer */;
fclose(fp); // fp2 is still open
/* do something with fp2 */
fclose(fp2);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `fileno` to get a descriptor for a `FILE*`, `dup` that, and then use `fdopen` to get a new `FILE*` from the new descriptor.

Answer (score 26):

```
FILE *fp2 = fdopen (dup (fileno (fp)), "r");
```

Answer (score -1):

I opened twice the same file and assigned two pointers and in the end closed both separately. In my case I had to show the content in a text window using one pointer and process the data in file using the other pointer.
e.g.

```
//define global variables

FILE *fp1 = fopen("some_file", "r");

//fp1 used in functioncall to display textbuffer 

fclose(fp1); 

//fp2 used in functioncall to process data 

fclose(fp2);
```