# How can I keep the position of a FILE pointer in a file in another file pointer?

Tags: c, file, file-pointer

I have the following code in which the `tmp` `FILE *` does not keep the previous position of `fp` (which is 0). It actually changes along with `fp` when I use `fseek()`.

Output:

```
fp=0 fp=40 tmp=40
```

How can I make it work such that `tmp` keeps the original position?

```
main()
{
        FILE *fp,*tmp;
        char *name;

        name=getfilename();

        if((fp=fopen(name,"wb"))==NULL)
        {
                puts("\n CAN'T OPEN FILE FOR SAVING...\n");
                return ;
        } 

        printf("fp=%ld",ftell(fp));

        tmp=fp;

        fseek(fp,sizeof(int)*10,SEEK_SET);

        printf("fp=%ld tmp=%ld",ftell(fp),ftell(tmp));
}
```

Comment: Both `tmp` and `fp` point to the same thing, so any modification to one pointer will "affect" the other. If I understand your question correctly, you basically want 2 different read/write positions within the same file stream, correct?

Comment: yes..correct.How can this be done?

Comment: @matts what about just using `ftell` to get the position and `fseek` to restore it?

Comment: AFAIK this is not "natively" supported, I imagine due to some sort of race condition and/or ambiguity. I think one alternative is to manually save and restore the position as you need it?

Comment: Depending on the system (ie not windows): `tmp = fopen(name, "rb"); fseek(tmp, ftell(fp), SEEK_SET);` But be _very, very, very_ careful

Comment: Please see the below link - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099315/duplicating-file-pointers>

Comment: If supported (ie linux), you could open the file using `open` with `O_SYNC` flag, to ensure the fd blocks the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pointers point to the same FILE structure. If you wish, you can simply open the file twice, in which case, the pointers would be entirely independent.